# Aligning multiple texts in a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, text

I have three variables that have varying values with different length for those values. For example:

```
var a = "123456"
var b = "23,000.00"
var c = "Accounts Receivable"
```

The values can change for these three variables.

I have a long button that I would like to show these values in. Right now i'm using *&nbsp* to space them out in the button. However, since the values can change, and their length can be grow or shrink, I need to adapt. For a start, the first value can be aligned left, second aligned center, and the third variable can be aligned right. How do I achieve this?

```js
a = "123456"
b = "23,000.00"
c = "Accounts Receivable"

jQuery("#column_1").html("");
jQuery("#column_3").html("<span style='color:#FFFFFF'> Variable1&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspVariable2&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspVariable3</span>");

jQuery("#column_1").append('<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" class="list-group-item" >' + a + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" + b + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" + c + '</button></div>');

b = "100,000,000.00"

jQuery("#column_1").append('<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" class="list-group-item" >' + a + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" + b + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" + c + '</button></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id="grid" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="column_1">
          <div class="list-group"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Unless you can break each text "item" into separate elements I don't see a way of doing that. CSS can spread elements but not unless they are separate,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the data in `span` elements, and apply flexbox properties to `.list-group-item` in your CSS.

example:

```js
a = "123456"
b = "23,000.00"
c = "Accounts Receivable"

jQuery("#column_1").html("");
jQuery("#column_3").html("<span style='color:#FFFFFF'> Variable1&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspVariable2&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspVariable3</span>");

jQuery("#column_1").append('<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" class="list-group-item" ><span>' + a + '</span><span>' + b + '</span><span>' + c + '</span></button></div>');

b = "100,000,000.00"

jQuery("#column_1").append('<div class="col-md-auto"> <button type="button" class="list-group-item" ><span>' + a + '</span><span>' + b + '</span><span>' + c + '</span></button></div>');
```

```css
.list-group-item {
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class='sapUiBody'>
  <div id="grid" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div id="column_1">
          <div class="list-group"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use specified width inline block divs

```
<div style="width: 150px;display: inline-block;">Value 1</div>
<div style="width: 150px;display: inline-block;">Value 2</div>
<div style="width: 150px;display: inline-block;">Value 3</div>
```

inside your button for example, there are many ways to do this with css only

and maybe it's worth just knowing that [button groups](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/button-group/) exists, i don't really know what you want this button for